# Why does tr/a-z/b/d replace a in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

Why does `tr/a-z/b/d` replace character `a` in perl? Isn't it meant to delete all characters from `a to z`?

```
$string = 'the cat sat on the mat.';
$string =~ tr/a-z/b/d;

print "$string\n"; # => b b   b. Why?
```

Comment: What did you expect? And why?

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators):

> If the `/d` modifier is used, the REPLACEMENTLIST is always interpreted exactly as specified. Otherwise, if the REPLACEMENTLIST is shorter than the SEARCHLIST, the final character is replicated till it is long enough.

Since you used the `/d` modifier, `REPLACEMENTLIST` is not extended. So `a` is replaced with `b`, and the rest of the letters matched by `a-z` are deleted because there's nothing in `REPLACEMENTLIST` to replace them with.

If you do it without the `/d` modifier, you'll get your expected behavior. It will be equivalent to:

```
tr/a-z/bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb/
```

because of the replication.

Comment: Wait I think I understand. Are you saying the `/d`modifier is used to replace the search list with the replacement list?

Comment: No. The `/d` modifier means to delete anything in the search list that doesn't have a corresponding character in the replacement list. It's usually used when the replacement list is empty, to mean that everything in the search list should be deleted.

Answer (score 4):

The search list is `a-z`. The replacement list is `b`. The option `/d` is given. This means replace `a` with `b`, and delete all other matches that have no replacement. Documentation [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#tr/SEARCHLIST/REPLACEMENTLIST/cdsr).

Comment: So when using `/d`, it replaces the first character in the search list with the first character in the replacement list that is if there is only one character in the replacement list?

Answer (score 3):

The second range is shorter than the first. So a gets replaced by b, and b-z get replaced by the empty string because of the extra d flag at the end.